# Support for Side DB in Composer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Are there any plans for composer, to make usage of the recently released Side DB feature (https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151)?

As a developer I would like to be able to submit private data with composer-client and choose, which organisations are allowed to access that data.

I know I can call the native fabric API, but then I can't use the composer features, such as ACLs.

Answer (score 1):

its not supported in Composer yet at this present time, but there are plans. Most of SideDB production-ready features are planned for Fabric v1.2 (per related https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8718) and its experimental in Fabric v1.1.